# Weird content move on my webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css

i developed this site.

http://www.chipotlelabs.com/apps/

It works fine , but when i run with a hash like:

http://www.chipotlelabs.com/apps/#Instaplayer

my content randomly moves.. any ideas whats going on?

heres a part of my code, im using the move.js library and the jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library.

```
case 'Instaplayer':
$('#cuerpoinsta').waitForImages({
    waitForAll: true,
    finished: function() {
        // All images have loaded.
        $(window).unbind('mousewheel');
        $("#accion").css("display", "none");
        $("#header").animate({
            height: "120px"
        }, 1000);
        $("#fondorepeat").animate({
            height: "120px"
        }, 1000);

        $("#logo").animate({
            "margin-top": "15px",
            'margin-left': '370px',
            width: "216px",
            height: "75px"
        }, 900, function() {


            $("#sombramenu").fadeIn('fast');
            fixedtotal()

            $("#primerasfotos").css('display', 'block');

            if ($(window).height() < 670) {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
                    demas();
                    $("#uno").attr({
                        'src': 'images/1x.jpg',
                        'rel': 'images/1x_thumb.png'
                    })
                    $("#dos").attr({
                        'src': 'images/2x.jpg',
                        'rel': 'images/2x_thumb.png'
                    })
                    $("#tres").attr({
                        'src': 'images/3x.jpg',
                        'rel': 'images/3x_thumb.png'
                    })
                    $("#cuatro").attr({
                        'src': 'images/4x.jpg',
                        'rel': 'images/4x_thumb.png'
                    })
                    $("#cinco").attr({
                        'src': 'images/5x.jpg',
                        'rel': 'images/5x_thumb.png'
                    })
                    $('html,body').stop(true, false).animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#instacont").offset().top - 88
                    }, 1000, function() {
                        move("#sloganinsta").set('opacity', 1).scale(0.7).set('margin-left', '60px').set('margin-top', '100px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end()
                        move("#instafoto").set('opacity', 1).scale(0.7).set('margin-left', '0px').set('margin-top', '115px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end()
                        move("#appletv").set('opacity', 1).scale(0.7).set('margin-left', '460px').set('margin-top', '380px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end()
                        move("#labadgeinsta").set('opacity', 1).scale(0.7).set('margin-left', '480px').set('margin-top', '325px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end()
                        move("#fraseinsta").set('opacity', 1).scale(0.7).set('margin-left', '465px').set('margin-top', '240px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end()
                        move("#fraseotra").set('opacity', 1).scale(0.7).set('margin-left', '180px').set('margin-top', '290px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end(function() {

                            $("#primerasfotos").css('top', '42%');
                            $(".carro").css({
                                'margin-left': '420px',
                                'margin-top': '320px'
                            });
                            move(".carro").scale(0.7).end();
                            move("#slogan").set('opacity', 1).scale(0.7).set('margin-left', '60px').set('margin-top', '50px').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').duration('0.6s').end(function() {

                                move("#pluma").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '144px').set('margin-top', '442px').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').set("width", "200px").duration('0.6s').end(function() {});
                                move("#iphone").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '250px').set('margin-top', '305px').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').set('width', '100px').duration('0.6s').end(function() {});

                                move("#moleskine").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '305px').set('margin-top', '257px').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').set('width', '151px').duration('0.6s').end(function() {});
                                move("#ipad").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '399px').set('margin-top', '210px').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').set("width", "350px").duration('0.6s').end(function() {})

                                demas();

                                $("#nf").removeClass('activo');
                                $("#calcpad").removeClass('activo');
                                $("#insta").addClass('activo');





                            });


                        })

                    })
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
                    demas();
                    $('html,body').stop(true, false).animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#instacont").offset().top - 150
                    }, 1000, function() {

                        move("#sloganinsta").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '25px').set('margin-top', '50px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end()
                        move("#instafoto").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '0px').set('margin-top', '115px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end()
                        move("#appletv").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '565px').set('margin-top', '426px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end()
                        move("#labadgeinsta").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '575px').set('margin-top', '340px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end()
                        move("#fraseinsta").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '575px').set('margin-top', '240px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end()
                        move("#fraseotra").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '15px').set('margin-top', '125px').duration('0.6s').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').end(function() {

                            move("#slogan").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '60px').set('margin-top', '46px').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').duration('0.6s').end(function() {

                                move("#pluma").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '67px').set('margin-top', '499px').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').duration('0.6s').end(function() {
                                    move("#iphone").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '234px').set('margin-top', '320px').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').duration('0.6s').end(function() {

                                        move("#moleskine").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '305px').set('margin-top', '267px').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').duration('0.6s').end(function() {
                                            move("#ipad").set('opacity', 1).scale(1).set('margin-left', '445px').set('margin-top', '220px').ease('cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)').duration('0.6s').end(function() {


                                                $("#nf").removeClass('activo');
                                                $("#insta").addClass('activo');
                                                $("#calcpad").removeClass('activo');
                                                e.stopPropagation();


                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });

                        })


                    })
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        })
    }
})

break;
```

Comment: I dont see anything weird happening. Sorry

Comment: Are you factoring in the scrollbar appearing when you jump to a hash? That seems to be the only (unplanned) movement I see.

Comment: if you look really close you see the content moves like a bit to the right then a bit to the left.

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, or in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.